# Grails application loading takes long time?

Tags: grails, startup

I am using Grails 2.2.1 and java version:jdk1.7.0.79

Application has 25 controller and Database has not much data but still application taking more than 9 min to load the home page.

Tried changing the jdk version jdk1.7.25 and increased memory size but still facing same issue. Please help to resolve this.

Comment: I think you need to add more logs in the home page and find out the code that is causing the delay.

Answer (score 0):

You should update to latest JDK version 1.8.
Then rebuild app and run.